# Marcus,problem 12, chapter 3

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization

I'm trying to solve this exercise from Marcus' book "Number fields". Following Marcus notation, let me call $S=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$, and $R=\mathbb{Z}$.

- Firstly I proved that $5S=P_1P_2$ where $P_1=(5,\alpha+2)$ and $P_2=(5,\alpha^2+3\alpha-1)$. Indeed $P_1P_2=5(5,\alpha^2+4\alpha+1,\alpha^2+\alpha)$. Now, remember $1+\alpha+\alpha^2$ is a unit in $S$. It easy to see that $3 \in (5,\alpha^2+4\alpha+1,\alpha^2+\alpha)$, and so $(\alpha^2+4\alpha+1)-(3\alpha) =1+\alpha+\alpha^2 \in (5,\alpha^2+4\alpha+1,\alpha^2+\alpha) $.Thus, $(5,\alpha^2+4\alpha+1,\alpha^2+\alpha) =S$.
- There is an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^3+3x-1) $ and $ \mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,x^3+3x-1)$ which rises up from the homomorphism

> $\phi :\mathbb{Z}_5[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,x^3+3x-1) \qquad f(x) \mapsto f(x) + (5,x^3+3x-1)$

- Moreover, there is an homomorphism $\psi$ from $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,x^3+3x-1)$ to $S/(5,\alpha^2+3\alpha-1)$.
- Now, troubles start. Using the previous points I should be able to conclude that either   $S/(5,\alpha^2+3\alpha-1)$ is a field of order 25, or $S=(5,\alpha^2+3\alpha-1)$. I have no ideas, any hints?
- The last point is showing that $S \neq (5,\alpha^2+3\alpha-1)$. I think this is because, otherwise, $P_1P_2=P_1S=5S$, and $\alpha+2 \in P_1S$ but $\alpha+2$ doesn't lie in $5S$. I'm not sure about this last my statement, if you have other ideas, they will be kindly accepted.

Here you can read the exercise
[image]

Comment: It will be helpfull if you write what it says the exercise you want to solve.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to more clearly distinguish your work from your questions or more precisely state the latter. Some parts of your work are just sketches and it is a little hard to tell if you're asking for help with those details too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What (b) says is that
$$\mathbb Z[x]/(5,x^2+3x-1) \cong (\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)[x]/(x^2+3x-1).$$
Since $x^2 + 3x - 1$ is irreducible mod $5$, that means the latter is a field extension of degree $2$ of $\mathbb F_5$ i.e. the field with 25 elements.

That means in (c) we have shown that there is a surjection from the field $\mathbb F_{25}$ to $S/(5,\alpha^2+3\alpha-1)$. The only possible homomorphic images of a field are itself or the 0 ring, and so either $S/(5,\alpha^3+3\alpha -1)$ is $0$ or all of $\mathbb F_{25}$. The first would say that the ideal you are modding out by is all of $S$.

Your argument for (e) seems to be on the right track. From (a), we have $P_1 P_2 = 5S$. If $P_2 = S$, then that implies $P_1 = 5S$ but as you observed, $\alpha + 2$ is not in $5S$. I am not sure why you are unsure about this. Note that $5S$ is the ideal of $\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$ whose coefficients are all divisible by $5$, and evidently the coefficients of $\alpha+2$ are not divisible by $5$.

Surjection in part (c). First of all, there is clearly a map
$$\mathbb Z[x] \rightarrow S/(5,\alpha^2+3\alpha - 1)$$
which is induced by evaluating $x$ at $\alpha$ to go to $S$ and then applying the quotient map. This is a surjection because both maps are surjections. The quotient is always a surjection, and for the first recall that $S = \mathbb Z [\alpha]$, so all its elements are polynomials in $\alpha$ with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients. All we have to do now is check that the kernel of this map contains $(5,x^2 +3x - 1)$ and then the above surjection factors through the quotient to give us the map described above.

But this is easy; $5$ and $x^2 + 3x - 1$ are sent to the classes $\bar 5, \overline{\alpha^2 + 3\alpha - 1}$ in $S/(5,\alpha^2+3\alpha - 1)$ and those are certainly $0$ in that quotient.

Comment: You pointed out my main problems. I apologize for the lack of details. For point e) I reasoned as you did, but you know, maybe there could be some tricky trick that could state $\alpha+2 \in 5S$. I wanted to be sure

Comment: The reason there are no tricks is that $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$ are linearly independent, and $5S$ is the $\mathbb Z$-span of $\{5,5\alpha,5\alpha^2\}$ so it's not possible to get a coefficient not divisible by $5$. Your intuition is actually in the right spot - if you weren't using linearly independent elements then the argument doesn't go through.

Comment: Thanks! I have another doubt: why is the ring homomorphism in c)  a surjection? It seems to me that $S/(5,\alpha^2+3\alpha-1) \cong \mathbb{F}_5$ right? So, in this case, the homomorphism is clearly a projection.

Comment: Well, it's not possible for $\mathbb F_{5^2}$ to project (as a ring) onto $\mathbb F_5$. It is a field so the only image it can have is itself or trivial. I will add an explanation of the surjection to my answer.